# I want to know how my data should be in text file in relative to following script?

Tags: apache-pig

I want to know  how my data should be text file in relative to following script?
How pig differentiate delimiter for following script?
Please give me sample one row of input?

`A = LOAD 'mydata.txt' AS (P:int, T1:tuple(f1:int, f2:int), B:{T2:(t1:int,t2:int)}, M:[] );`

Answer (score 0):

At first, there is a document:

- [Load/Store Functions](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/func.html#load-store-functions)

And, see this:

- [Apache Pig - Not able to read the bag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865424/apache-pig-not-able-to-read-the-bag)

Sample data:

```
30|(1,2)|{(3,4)}|[]
```

Sample code:

```
A = LOAD 'mydata.txt' USING PigStorage('|') AS (P:int, T1:tuple(f1:int, f2:int), B:{T2:(t1:int,t2:int)}, M:[] );
DUMP A;
```

It seems `PigStorage` cannot determine commas in `bag`. I guess it's bug.